# 0x protocol swap api not fetching liquidity from pancakeswap

Tags: pancakeswap, 0x, goerli

I created a liquidity pool on pancakeswap for an asset pair for goerli network. I get this error when i try and fetch the price.

here is the api request
https://goerli.api.0x.org/swap/v1/price?sellToken=0x3870419Ba2BBf0127060bCB37f69A1b1C090992B&buyToken=0x3820a50d5670012d296AB1DDf75bB97790A8c9e1&sellAmount=1000000000000000000

here is the response
{
"code": 100,
"reason": "Validation Failed",
"validationErrors": [
{
"field": "sellAmount",
"code": 1004,
"reason": "INSUFFICIENT_ASSET_LIQUIDITY",
"description": "We are not able to fulfill an order for this token pair at the requested amount due to a lack of liquidity"
}
]
}

Is there any way to fix this issue ? what if i do the same on mainnet. Will this still be the issue ? Is there a given list of dexes that 0x api fetches the data from? is pancakeswap not in the list ?

Comment: This can happen at any time and any chain due to the lack of liquidity and for Pancake Swap, I don't think 0x is a good option because it focuses more on Ethereum and Ethereum sidechains.

Comment: But the network i used was goerli which is an ethereum testnet.  The dex i used was pancakeswap.

Comment: The error you received says there is insufficient liquidity for this item , Your only way to solve this error is to add liquidity to this currency pair in this network and in this DEX